# Second value isn't showing me assets htaccess (pretty URL)

Tags: .htaccess, url

my htaccess looks like this right now:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /bu/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?s=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$ index.php?s=$1&id=$2
```

and it is working without any problems when I'm passing my URL like this: "http:.//mysite.com/bu/user". But when I'm passing the URL like this: "http:.//mysite.com/bu/user/81", assets won't show because the path to (for example) CSS is broken. The real path is "http:.//mysite.com/bu/assets/css/main.css" but because of this bug it is causing the path to be like this: "http:.//mysite.com/bu/user/assets/css/main.css".
How can I fix it?

BTW: I had to put the dot between the "http:" and "//" so I can disable the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following base tag to the header of your document :

```
<base href="/bu/">
```

This will correct the header uri base for your js, css and relative links.